# How do you convert a string to 7-bit ASCII with even parity?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a string to 7-bit ASCII with even parity in a C# application which communicates with a mainframe. I tried using `Encoding.ASCII`, however, it does not have the correct parity.

Comment: i have tried using utf32 utf7,utf8,encoding and default but not working basically want a "," character to be converted to ox82

Comment: Those are _all_ Unicode encodings. You can try the `ASCII` encoding, though it is 8bit.

Comment: What would you want to happen to non-ASCII strings?

Comment: i want to pass it to mainframe system which accept only7-bit ASCII with even parity.

Comment: Maybe a start would be to convert to 8 bit ascii using Encondig.ASCII and then calculate the parity bit by using XOR on the first 7 bits. Then you'd repalace the 8th bit with your calculated parity bit. You'd also need to consider if your output is big or litte endian and what endianess the mainframe will need.

Comment: @ankush: My other question would be is this byte level parity or word level parity? And I echo mortb's question of what endianness are we looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public static byte[] StringTo7bitAsciiEvenParity(string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(((((bytes[i] * 0x0101010101010101UL) & 0x8040201008040201UL) % 0x1FF) & 1) == 0)
        {
            bytes[i] &= 0x7F;
        }
        else
        {
            bytes[i] |= 0x80;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Completely untested. Don't ask me how the magic to compute parity works. I just [found it here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityWith64Bits). But some variant of this should do what you want.

I tried to make this work for the case `','` becoming 0x82. But I can't work out how that is supposed to be done. `','` is, in ASCII, binary 00101100 and 0x82 is binary 10000010. I don't see the correlation at all.

Comment: `,` should become `10101100b` or `0xAC`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Good, that was what I got as well. The rest seems to match with the parity table you linked to as well. By the way, I think your way of not clearing the top bit on non-7bit ASCII data is probably better than what I did.

Comment: I think the default for Encoding.ASCII will throw an exception in the case where it is non-ASCII data.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to calculate the parity bit yourself. So:

1. convert string into byte array using built in 8bit ASCII encoding. Most top bit should allways be 0 using this encoding.
2. do the bit modifications on each byte and set parity bit for each byte.

There is no built-in functionality for calculating parity bit, that I know of.

Comment: [A bit twiddling trick can help.](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityParallel)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming byte-level parity and no-endian related behavior (i.e. a stream of bytes), the following works as intended (tested against a known [7-bit ASCII even parity table](http://telecom.tbi.net/ascii7e.html)):

```
public static byte[] GetAsciiBytesEvenParity(this string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

    for(int ii = 0; ii < bytes.Length; ii++)
    {
        // parity test adapted from: 
        // http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityParallel
        if (((0x6996 >> ((bytes[ii] ^ (bytes[ii] >> 4)) & 0xf)) & 1) != 0)
        {
            bytes[ii] |= 0x80;
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}
```